# PostSharp Logging line by line

Tags: logging, line, postsharp

Does PostSharp support logging each line executed, or just function calls?

I have a program that randomly fails two or three times a week.  I want to see the line and related info that the code is failing on.  It just dies when it fails, so I will end up seeing the last successful line run.  I know Postsharp will log function by function call for me.  Will it also do line by line?

Comment: So is there any tool that will automatically log every line number that runs in a program execution?  The program randomly fails, but the failure causes a crash, so the error trap is not being run and I don't know which line it occurs on.  PostSharp tells me the function that is happening on the failure (because it is being written to the log for every step - thus before it errors out and crashes).  But if I could log the last successful line run, I could determine which line causes the crash.

Comment: I suppose I could change every function call to a delegate being passed in and then wrap the delegate call with logging of some form.  But for currently existing projects, I now need to write a program that uses Roslyn that will go through all of my DotNet files and do some automated modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do that automatically and, in general, I think it would generate huge logs that would be difficult to read.

The recommended approach in this case is to combine automatic logging on method entry/exit with [manual logging](https://doc.postsharp.net/log-custom-messages) at essentials forking points within the offending method -- for instance, add logging inside `if` and `foreach` blocks.